# IO to pinned memory

Tags: linux, io, operating-system, kernel

What would be the downside of reading from device directly into user space pinned memory? Unable to find anywhere explaining this.

What advantage does reading via multi-step - reading from device into kernel buffer and copying contents from kernel buffer to user space - provide?

For later approach, if DMA is involved then I assume kernel buffer pages would be pinned anyway.
Why can't we directly pin user space pages and read into user space directly? Extra copying would always have performance penalty.

I think read() system call too does IO in multi-step way that I described (based on how reading from InputStream in Java works)

Comment: I/O often requires aligned memory, you may not be able to guarantee that for buffers in user space.

Comment: You seem to be asking about "Zero Copy I/O".  It's a thing.  And it is not new.  Here is an explanation: https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6345

Comment: @Barmar: A few additional concerns include: (1) the CPU may be able to address a larger physical memory space than DMA masters, (2) DMA masters may require contiguous physical addresses, while user buffers may have contiguous virtual addresses but be scattered all over physical RAM (3) Sort of the reverse problem, user space might allocate a lot of small buffers which end up fragmented to many pages, pinning all these pages would cause problems by tying up too much system RAM.

Comment: Thanks @BenVoigt. All the points you mentioned makes sense. But, did not understand how would pinning "a lot of small buffers which end up fragmented to many pages" be a disadvantage? I mean user program would invoke system call to read into "single" buffer only. And, wouldn't kernel allocate buffer of same size as user defined buffer and pin it and read into it from device? How would space be wasted if user defined buffer pages are pinned and not wasted when kernel buffer pages are pinned?

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. As I understand it, unaligned memory would entail more memory accesses. But when we use kernel buffers to read in, we would anyway have to make extra memory access (and writes) as we copy from kernel buffer to user buffer. Am I missing something?

Comment: @RahulPatel: Unaligned access is more memory accesses on a processor architecture that automatically handles the misalignment.  Note that it is a behavior of the processor, not the memory bus.  Other processors on the same bus may not be capable of unaligned access AT ALL.

Comment: @RahulPatel: As for fragmentation of small buffers being a problem for direct DMA (zero copy) my thinking is that when kernel buffers are used, they will be packed into a small number of pages, no matter how fragmented the user buffers are.  Even if I/O virtualization is in effect, a kernel page can still be shared by multiple buffers owned by the same guest.   The kernel must allocate a buffer the same size as the user I/O request length, not the same size as the entire user object owning the buffer.

Comment: Hmmm. got it @BenVoigt. So if user buffer is fragmented, multiple DMA requests might need to be made which might worsen the performance. Barring this case (I don't think there is a way to create "unfragmented" buffer and not really in control of user program), if I know my processor architecture supports auto-alignment of memory words reading into user space pinned pages would perform better than "read" system call (or in the worst case same performace in case of misalignment of memory words). Why is IO via zero-copy not the norm then? Would it be because of need of portability of software?

Comment: "if I know my processor architecture supports auto-alignment of memory words reading into user space pinned pages would perform better"  Make sure you are not thinking of CPU architecture, but of architecture of the bus master (disk controller, network card, etc).

Comment: Also, if some processors do not support auto-memory alignment, how would memory mapping work on systems running on top them? Reading a page into memory on page fault would, I assume, same operations.

Comment: @RahulPatel: Are you talking about the general purpose computer "system" or the bus-mastering DMA peripheral.  Most peripherals do not do virtual memory or memory mapping.  I/O virtualization is very new.  And in any case, swapping an entire page in or out is always an aligned operation.

Comment: I seem to be mixing up the terminology. Sorry. Let me be explicit. I understood that some peripheral device controllers might not work well with un-aligned access. However, as far as reading a file from secondary storage (HDD or SSD) is concerned I do not see any downside of reading file via memory map compared to via "read" system call. I wanted to understand the caveats if any. Also, I would be very grateful if you could provide some materials that explains these concepts. Zero Copy I/O article you provided was very enlightening

Comment: Generically speaking, how does kernel ensure that device access is aligned? Does kernel allocate slightly larger buffer if user buffer is unaligned? How does kernel know how many bytes-aligned each device is?

Comment: Buffer allocation is the responsibility of each kernel device driver as it sets up DMA.  The device driver knows the device's alignment requirement, because it is written for the specific device (family).

Comment: Understood Ben. Thanks a lot.